# NodeJS + Express 3 - Slashes in Route and then a fixed operation

Tags: regex, node.js, routes

I am having trouble with this route:

```
app.get('/project/:handle/browse/:filepath(.*)/children', files.children);                          //getting contents of any node in the directory structure
```

I want the route to parse the url which includes a `:filepath` parameter, which can include slashes, and then a `/children` operation. The `(.*)` is my failed attempt at placing a regex restriction on the `:filepath` parameter.

I want to use such a scheme for permalinking purposes, so moving some of the route arguments to parameters is not an option, and URI encoding would make them ugly... I have looked around but it seems like all the answers on stackoverflow are geared towards an argument with slashes at the end of the url, like:

```
app.get('/project/:path', files.children);
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm afraid that you will have to use regex routes. http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.VERB

Comment: You could come with a regexp to do that, but what will happen if the filepath ends with '/children' ?

Comment: Laurent, I think there would be no problems, because you need to have a trailing /children anyway. The filepath would parse to "something/children", for an url like something/children/children.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, I figured it out, I went the regex way! The answer (and working code) is posted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to use regex routes, as per gustavohenke's comment. Here is the working code!

```
    app.get(/project\/(([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9])+)\/browse\/(.+)\/children/,
        function(req,res)
        {
            req.params.handle = req.params[0];     //project handle
            req.params.filepath = req.params[2];   //relative path
            files.children(req, res);
        }
    );                          //getting contents of any node in the directory structure
```

The trick is to know that each "slice" of the url will be available in the req.params[] array whenever you use a `(something)` section in the route. Use an inline callback function and use it to copy each element of the array to the human-readable parameters in the controller action...then call the controller method as normal.

As for the regex itself, I escaped the `/` (slashes) in the regex by writing `\/` and used the `(.+)` statement in it, which means "any character `(.)` at least one time (`+`). If you wanted any character zero or more times you would use `(.*)`

Thanks for pointing me the right way.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
app.get('/project/:handle/browse/:filepath*/children', function(req, res) {
  var filepath = req.params.filepath + (req.params[0] || '');
   ...
});
```

Comment: A nice suggestion, I tried it and it works! However, I believe my answer may help people with different problems as the explanation is more complete. I will upvote but will accept my answer unless a more interesting one appears. I am being objective as the score for accepting mine is the same as accepting yours... Peace!